# error unused argument for gene_ontology function

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a gene ontology analysis in R and I got this error;

```
Error in get_ontology(x, name = paste("Cluster", names(df.list[i]), "Pathways_for_kmeans_cluster",  : 
  unused argument (name = paste("Cluster", names(df.list[i]), "Pathways_for_kmeans_cluster", j, sep = "_"))
```

after I run this script:

```
numclus <- sort(unique(df.list[[i]]$kmeans.cluster))
subdirname <- paste("D:/Master jaar 1/RP1/RP1 projects/Aged macrophage characterisation/Single cell sequencing/nieuwe stuff", "/top100_genes_from_", names(df.list[i]), "_pathways_from_kmeans_clusters", sep = " ")
dir.create(subdirname, showWarnings = FALSE)
install.packages("ontologyPlot")


for (j in numclus){
   x <- data.frame(gene = rownames(df.list[[i]][which(df.list[[i]]$kmeans.cluster == j),]), avg_logFC = 0)}
   if(nrow(x)>10){
     get_ontology(x, name = paste("Cluster", names(df.list[i]), "Pathways_for_kmeans_cluster", j, sep = "_"), return.data = F, outdir = subdirname, full_GSEA = F)
   }
 }
```

I get the error after the line with get_ontology

Comment: The first argument of function `get_ontology` is `file` and it's described as *"File path of OBO formatted file."*. Please read the help pages of the functions you are using, `help('get_ontology')`.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that `get_ontology` doesn't have an argument called `name`.  You haven't told us which packages you're using, so I can't help you further, but you might get somewhere by loooking at the online help.

Comment: the package I am using is ontologyIndex

Comment: Then you should know that `get_ontology` has arguments called, `file`, `propogate_relationships` and `extract_tags`.  Not name.  All the information you need is in the online package documentation.  After loading the package with `library()`, type `?get_ontology`.